# How to find Bitnami LMS powered by Moodle™ LMS Admin Credentials?

Tags: moodle, bitnami, macos-monterey

I've downloaded Bitnami Moodle (https://bitnami.com/stack/moodle/installer) 4.0.4-1 and installed it. According to this article (https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/moodle/get-started/first-steps/) I need to click on "Open Terminal" button and run the command `sudo cat /home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials` to get the admin credentials.

But the issue I'm facing is the **Terminal is not opening** eventhough I click on "Open Terminal" button.

Is there any other way to access the credentials?

Machine Details : MacBook Pro Intel running macOS Monterey

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround I found.

1. Install QEMU (https://www.qemu.org/download/)
2. Goto your bitnami installation folder (Users/<username>/.bitnami/stackman/machines/moodle)
3. Go to the vm folder. It should have a file named **machine.qcow2**
4. Open the terminal in the VM folder and convert the above file into **vdi** format using the following command. `qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vdi machine.qcow2 machine.vdi` ( Ref : https://docs.openstack.org/image-guide/convert-images.html)
5. Download and install VirtualBox (https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)
6. Download Ubuntu Image (https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
7. Create a virtual machine using VirtualBox and install Ubuntu on it.
8. Goto settings of the above created virual machine and add the **machine.vdi** created in step 4 as a virtual harddisk.
9. Turn on the virtual machine and you should see the newly added virtual disk.
10. You can open "/home/bitnami/bitnami_credentials" file using text editor in Ubuntu and find out the credentials.